# Add image on tableview customise button background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i want to add image on a button which is on tableview cell, this is my code, all is working but after picking the image , its not set or visible on `imagebutton`, please help me......

in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method

```
  if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
         cell.textLabel.text =@"Your Profile Photo";
         imageBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 5, 35, 35)];
           [imageBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AFPFriendThumbnail.png"]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imageBtn addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(myAction)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        [cell addSubview:imageBtn];

    }
```

action on button

```
-(void)myAction
{    
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[imageBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected];
imageBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[tableView_ reloadData];
}
```

Comment: try to reload cell like this:
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

Comment: can you show the first image (AFPFriendThumbnail.png) on button..or not.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `UIControlStateNormal`

```
[imageBtn setImage:image forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

But i could see you reloading the tableView after setting the image, this will replace the `imageBtn`

```
 imageBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 5, 35, 35)]; // Creating a button every time.
```

It should work with out reloading, since you are keeping the reference to the `imageBtn` so that you can directly set. Try by removing `[tableView_ reloadData]`

Comment: @RaviJSS See my edit, you are not getting because you reloading the tableView which will cause the button to to be replaced with a new. That probably you dont want

Answer (score 2):

You should **never** call reloadData or any of the cell reload methods in cellForRowAtIndexPath. That's going to cause an infinite recursion crash.

Also, you should only add views to a table view cell if you ask to dequeue a cell and it returns nil.

Instead, when yo get nil from the dequeue method, add your button and set it up with a unique tag. If you get back a recycled cell, fetch the button using viewWithTag and change the image and action as needed. (You'll need to remove the previous action, since buttons can have more than one action attached to them.)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
         imageBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 5, 35, 35)];
```

With this

```
         imageBtn = [[UIButton [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         imageBtn.frame=CGRectMake(250, 5, 35, 35);
```

And . . 
Replace

```
        [imageBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

With this..

```
        [imageBtn setImage:image forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

I hope this is helpful for you..